# android array from shared preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to iterate over a collection of shared preferences, and generate an ArrayList of HashMaps, but having an issue.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(pref, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("key1", "value1");
editor.putString("key2", "value2");
```

and then I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> LIST = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(pref, 0);
Map<String, ?> items = settings.getAll();
for(String s : items.keySet()){
    HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp.put("key", s);
    temp.put("value", items.get(s));
    LIST.add(temp);
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
The method put(String, String) in the type HashMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, capture#5-of ?)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Regardless of the API level, Check http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2012/05/string-arrays-and-object-arrays-in.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hache had the correct idea.  An Object is not a String, so .toString() was necessary.

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> LIST = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(pref, 0);
Map<String, ?> items = settings.getAll();
for(String s : items.keySet()){
    HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp.put("key", s);
    temp.put("value", items.get(s).toString());
    LIST.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: I'm new so I'm not questioning your answer, but rather asking a question :)  What about using Pair?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html

Comment: @Bill Mote - You mean in place of the HashMaps?  I suppose that would work, but the question was more on how to iterate through a set of preferences than it was in how to manipulate the resulting data.  My end aim was to have a String, so while Pair would have held the object, I would still have needed to get a pair of strings from it.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
 final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> LIST = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

to

```
 HashMap<String,?> temp = new HashMap<String,?>();
 final ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>> LIST = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>>();
```

and it should work. You're not putting an String but an object this causes the error

Comment: Cannot instantiate the type HashMap<String,?>